# When Doctrine Generate doctrine/base/*.class.php

Tags: doctrine, symfony1, file-permissions

I am having a web site live built with symfony 1 and Doctrine.

sometimes i get error like:

```
Doctrine don't have the permission to write on
../../../model/doctrine/base/BaseClassName.class.php
```

But i didn't change any permission. So why and when Doctrine regenerate those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base classes are generated when invoking

```
./symfony doctrine:build-model
```

or

```
./symfony doctrine:build
```

from command line. There's no code to generate these classes for you when it's not generated yet. You will get fatal error in that case.